# Verify Azure Table SAS-based credentials

Tags: java, azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

I'm looking for simple way of verifying an arbitrary Azure Table connection string that uses a SAS such as the one below using the Azure Storage's Java SDK:

`https://example.table.core.windows.net/example?sig=aaabbbcccdddeeefffggghhh%3D&se=2020-01-01T00%3A00%3A00Z&sv=2015-04-05&tn=example&sp=raud`

I tried a bunch of different methods exposed by the [CloudTable](https://azure.github.io/azure-sdk-for-java/com/microsoft/azure/storage/table/CloudTable.html) api, but none of them works.

- `CloudTable.exists()` throws a StorageException, regardless of whether the credentials are valid
- `getName()`, `getStorageUri()`, `getUri()`, and other getters - all work locally, regardless of the credentials
- `getServiceClient().downloadServiceProperties()` and `getServiceClient().getServiceStats()` also throw various exceptions, while  `getServiceClient().getEndpoint()` and `getServiceClient().getCredentials()` and others always work locally.
- Why don't I just query the Table for a row or two? Well, in many cases I need to verify a SAS that gives only write or update premissions (without `delete` or `read` permissions), and I do not want to execute a statement that changes something in the table just to check the credentials.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your questions:

> CloudTable.exists() throws a StorageException, regardless of whether
>   the credentials are valid

I believe there's a bug with the SDK when using this method with SAS Token. I remember running into the same issue some time back.

> getName(), getStorageUri(), getUri(), and other getters - all work
>   locally, regardless of the credentials

These will work as they don't make network call. They simply use the data available to them in the different instance variables and return the data.

> getServiceClient().downloadServiceProperties() and
>   getServiceClient().getServiceStats() also throw various exceptions,
>   while getServiceClient().getEndpoint() and
>   getServiceClient().getCredentials() and others always work locally.

In order for `getServiceClient().someMethod()` to work using SAS, you would need `Account SAS` instead of `Service SAS` (which you're using right now).

> Why don't I just query the Table for a row or two? Well, in many cases
>   I need to verify a SAS that gives only write or update premissions
>   (without delete or read permissions), and I do not want to execute a
>   statement that changes something in the table just to check the
>   credentials.

One possible way to check the validity of a SAS Token for write operation is to perform a write operation which you know will fail with an error. For example, you can try to insert an entity which is already there. In this case, you should get a `Conflict (409)` error. Other thing you could try to do is perform an optimistic write by specifying some random `Etag` value and check for `Precondition Failed (412)` error. If you get a 403 error or 404 error, that would indicate there's something wrong with your SAS token.

Comment: Thanks. The question isn't about why any of that stuff doesn't work, I just mentioned some things I've already tried. The question is about proposing a working solution. Your `Conflict` solution would work, but requires me to perform an insert or to know ahead of time which PartitionKey+RowKey already exist in the table. The Etag is an interesting idea, but I couldn't get it to work - I was able to insert dummy entities with completely random Etags, which again requires an insert just to check if the coordinates and credentials are valid. Am I missing something?

Comment: Now I am confused :). So you want to check the validity of the SAS Token without performing any inserts or updates or for that matter any network operation. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: I never said "without any network operation", that would clearly be impossible. I just don't want to change the state of the table every time I check a SAS. I'm looking for an operation that doesn't change anything in the table. For example, with Azure Queue, downloadAttributes() fits the bill - no state change, and it fails if the SAS is incorrect.

Comment: "perform a write operation which you know will fail"  This is brilliant and works flawlessly - sorry Malt didn't understand your solution.  To test Azure storage credentials I create a bucket with illegal name "a" - that fails with "OutOfRangeInput" if credentials are good, and a variety of other errors if creds are bad.  Same trick does not appear to work for Google cloud storage as they appear to check conformance of the name before validating the credentials.